# return list with anonymous type in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

How i can return list with anonymous type, because with this code i get

"The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

i need only return IdMember and UserName, thanks

```
    public static List<T> GetMembersItems(string ProjectGuid)
    {
        using (PMEntities context = new PMEntities("name=PMEntities"))
        {
            var items = context.Knowledge_Project_Members.Include("Knowledge_Project").Include("Profile_Information")
                        .Where(p => p.Knowledge_Project.Guid == ProjectGuid)
                        .Select(row => new { IdMember = row.IdMember, UserName = row.Profile_Information.UserName });

            return items.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: To use a generic return type like that you'd need to make it a generic method with an extra `<T>` like this: `public static List<T> GetMembersItems<T>(string ProjectGuid)`.  But you'd still have other problems...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 17):

The class **Tuple<>** is made for situations like this.  Creating a custom class as already suggested is clearer, but Tupple gets the job done too.

e.g.

```
.Select(row => new Tuple<int,string>(row.IdMember,row.Profile_Information.UserName))
```

to access the member properties at the other side of the wire, you'll need to use:

```
var id=t.Item1
var name=t.Item2
```

Comment: Tuples dont work in entity framework because you need to create them with their intializer function and entity framework only allows you to use types with default constructors

Comment: @Rabbi: You could project an anonymous type as an enumerable and then use a tuple to project in-memory. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118688/return-tuple-from-ef-select

Comment: How about ValueTuple?

Comment: Confirmed works with EF Core 6

Answer (score 7):

Because you're returning objects of an anonymous type, you cannot declare that in your return type for the method.  Your attempted use of the generic `<T>` won't work for this.  There is no type-safe way to declare a method like that.  If you declare your return type as `IList` then that should work, but you still won't have type safety.

You're really just better off declaring the type.

**Update:**

Declaring a simple return type isn't so bad.  You could write a class like this:

```
public class MemberItem
{
    public string IdMember { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And then write your method like this:

```
public static List<MemberItem> GetMembersItems(string ProjectGuid)
{
    using (PMEntities context = new PMEntities("name=PMEntities"))
    {
        var items = context.Knowledge_Project_Members.Include("Knowledge_Project").Include("Profile_Information")
                    .Where(p => p.Knowledge_Project.Guid == ProjectGuid)
                    .Select(row => new MemberItem { IdMember = row.IdMember, UserName = row.Profile_Information.UserName });

        return items.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, which is the best way to return a list with this select?

Answer (score 3):

Scope of anonymous types are limited to the method in which they are defined. In your case, you better declare a separate class with the relevant properties and return a collection of the instances of that class. For e.g.

```
public class UserDetail
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
}

public static List<UserDetail> GetMembersItems(string ProjectGuid)
    {
        using (PMEntities context = new PMEntities("name=PMEntities"))
        {
            var items = context.Knowledge_Project_Members.Include("Knowledge_Project").Include("Profile_Information")
                        .Where(p => p.Knowledge_Project.Guid == ProjectGuid)
                        .Select(row => new UserDetail{ IdMember = row.IdMember, UserName = row.Profile_Information.UserName });

            return items.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return anonymous types by casting them to Object, but this is rarely useful. However if you are returning it from say an WebApi controller as a quick and (not so) dirty DTO then I think it is perfectly fine.
This only works with JSON though. XML will complain about the schema or something, but nowadays everybody use JSON anyway :)

```
public static List<Object> GetMembersItems(string ProjectGuid)
{
    using (PMEntities context = new PMEntities("name=PMEntities"))
    {
        var items = context.Knowledge_Project_Members.Include("Knowledge_Project").Include("Profile_Information")
                    .Where(p => p.Knowledge_Project.Guid == ProjectGuid)
                    .Select(row => new { IdMember = row.IdMember, UserName = row.Profile_Information.UserName });

        return items
               .ToList() // this is only needed to make EF happy otherwise it complains about the cast
               .Cast<Object>()
               .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use and ArrayList instead

```
    public static ArrayList GetMembersItems(string ProjectGuid)
    {
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList(); 

              items.AddRange(yourVariable 
                        .Where(p => p.Knowledge_Project.Guid == ProjectGuid)
                        .ToList());
            return items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the type:NameValueCollection or KeyValuePair instead.
anonymous type can not be the return type.